# Browser mangling 302 responses from Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, redirect

I have the following.

1. AJAX request made to server from `mydomain.blah.com`
2. Server returns 302  **but** to a slight different domain `blah.com` not `mydomain.blah.com`
3. Browser appears to mangle response. Instead of the `302` coming into my error callback a response with no response body and no status code is returned.

Further details

- Looking at request in IE 10 it is marked as aborted.
- In FF , firebug shows the 302 coming back but it never been handled.

To complicate matters (although I don't this is relevant) there are multiple ajax requests sent over.

The reason why the 302 is returned is because my server session is timed out and I am being redirected to a login page. I don't have much control over the server.

I want to get the response code 302 sent from my server into my error callback. This is what I want to achieve.

The ajax calls are being made using JQuery.

Any help appreciated.

If it is offical policy for browsers to "mangle" 302 responses to difference domains from ajax calls then if anyone could provide a reference that would be cool. Then I'd know there is not much I can do about this.

Comment: Are you only using the success callback? If so, try using the error callback to capture this condition.

Comment: @Tharsan yes using error callback I have edited question.